# Matlab: count and sort data results in an inverse cumulative order

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

I have a script that cumulates my data and plots it afterwards. In my case my data are temperatures and the plots show the number of hours a year in which these temperatures and every temperature below are reached.

For example:

- in 7500 hours a year it is 25 degree and colder
- in 6000 hours a year it is 20 degree and colder

I get the result that i need using the matlab scrpit below:

```
    filenameTRY2035='TZ10.dat';
    daten = dlmread(filenameTRY2035);
    TZ10 = sort(daten(1:length(daten)));

    A = length(TZ7); A = A';

    % plot
    figure(1)
    clf(1)

    hold on;
    h1 = plot(TZ10,A);
```

Now I want the temperatures counted the other way around.

For example:

- in 1000 hours a year its 25 degrees and hotter
- in 3500 hours a year it is 20 degrees and hotter

Could anyone help me modify my script in the way that I get the plots I need?

Thanks a lot,
Cheyenne

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have

```
TZ10 =

        .... 7000  7300  7500 ....
```

> 7500 -> 25° or colder
>
> 7300 -> 24° or colder
>
> 7000 -> 23° or colder
>
> ...

And there are 8766 hours in a year.

Then the reversed order would be

```
l = length(TZ10);
TZ10_reverse(l) = 8766 - TZ10(1)
for temp = 2:l
    TZ10_reverse(l - temp + 1) = (8766 - TZ10(temp)) + (TZ10(temp) - TZ10(temp - 1));
end
```

Because if there are 8766 hours a year and 7500 hours equals or colder than 25° a year, then there are 8766 - 7500 **strictly** warmer than 25° a year and TZ10(25) - TZ10(24) days equals to 25°

I also did it in order to get it sorted!

*By the way....*

```
TZ10 = sort(daten(1:length(daten)));
```

is equivalent to

```
TZ10 = sort(daten);
```

The elements of `daten` from 1 to the max index of `daten` is basicly `daten` itself!